# Dúvida sobre arquivos em cache

Tags: html, css, cache

Galera estou montando um sisteminha em php, e estou criando o material design que vai ser usado no sistema. Criei 2 arquivos, 1º Materia.js e 2º Material.css.

Bom nestes arquivo vou colocar todo o CSS e JS. Irei chamar o arquivo na tela de login e da página logado.

Minha dúvida é toda vez que a pagina logado for carregada o bowser vai baixar os arquivos ou vai carregar ele do cache?

Isso vai deixar o sistema pesado?

Estou seguindo a forma que o Materializer funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso depende se quer que o servidor faça cache dos recursos ou não, isso pode ser visto num dos parametros dos headers de resposta do servidor requisitado, no caso do facebook é:

```
Cache-Control: "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
```

Isto quer dizer que não guarde nada em cache, renova sempre, e é privado (para o caso de ter alguma coisa em cache é só para mim). [Aqui](http://dev.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) e [aqui](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers#http-cache-headers) estão esses paramentros melhor explicados.

Para configurar o cache do seu servidor em php pode fazer:

```
header("Cache-Control: private, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Ou no html também pode, exs:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="private">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-store">
```

Ou htaccess ex:

```
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Neste caso, este htaccess serveria para o seu caso, guarda em cache os recursos com essas extenções. Mas note que isso poderia ser definido em php também

Um aspeto não diretamente relativo à pergunta, mas tem a haver com performance, é importante também fazer [gzip](https://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/) aos recursos, pode no `.htaccess` fazer:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Para responder à sua pergunta, você pode controlar isso no servidor e configurar com as suas preferências, aqui tem [mais uma](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/cache-control.html) referência.

Comment: hum, então é possível armazenar o JS e o CSS em cache, bom. Poderia me mostrar como fazer para o sistema armazenar o JS e CSS em cache publico e as PNG eu não quero salvar. Queria fazer isso via htaccess.

Comment: Tem o exemplo para isso na resposta, editei o htaccess @HugoBorges

Comment: ok muito obrigado

Comment: @HugoBorges, um alerta... Se estiver a trabalhar no site e não vir nada mudar é por isso, por causa desse cache